# Did white supremacists "mix-in" with groups protesting George Floyd's death?

Tags: united-states, politics

Donald Trump, citing Fox and Friends host Brian Kilmeade, [made a claim in the following tweet](https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/1267430825659899907?s=19)

> “I don’t see any indication that there were any white supremest groups mixing in. This is an ANTIFA Organization. It seems that the first time we saw it in a major way was Occupy Wall Street. It’s the same mindset.” 
>   @kilmeade
>   @foxandfriends
>     TRUE!

Given the widespread media coverage of the protests, including video documentation and multiple group organizations joining in, *were* white supremacist groups at protest sites?

Comment: The claim says there is no evidence of it. It'd probably make more sense to verify that claim rather than the opposite.

Comment: @TheWanderer: We should accept answers in either direction, so it should be equivalent.

Comment: with tens of thousands of americans showing up, odds are there were some there...

Comment: Donald Trump cite Fox host. Department of Safety Commissioner John Harrington cite their arrest records "some of the 40 arrests made in the Twin Cities Friday night were of people linked to white supremacist groups and organized crime"

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY That sounds like the beginning of a very good answer to me.

Comment: @Zibbobz I couldn't find any direct quote or hard data. I would prefer to avoid giving answer based on second hand source.

Comment: https://naomikritzer.com/2020/06/03/minneapolis-outside-agitators/

Comment: @DanielRHicks This appears to be a personal blog - which isn't a sufficiently credible source for Skeptics.se as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @Zibbobz - It does contain some links though.

Comment: https://www.cnn.com/2020/06/03/us/boogaloo-extremist-protests-invs/index.html

Comment: I don't want to sound conspiratorial, but there might be some serious efforts toward violent ends from *several* angles. [William Barr claims he has evidence Antifa is hijacking George Floyd protests](https://nypost.com/2020/06/04/william-barr-claims-he-has-evidence-antifa-is-hijacking-george-floyd-protests/) and [Right-wing extremists arrested for planning riots at protests in Las Vegas](https://nypost.com/2020/06/04/right-wing-extremists-planned-riots-at-las-vegas-protests-feds/).

Comment: @fredsbend Understandable - this question is focused on one aspect of that.  I would say that a second question confirming evidence of Antifa hijacking would be appropriate, given the extraordinary claim of William Barr.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to the [NY Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/05/31/us/george-floyd-protests-white-supremacists-antifa.html):

> Members of hate groups or far-right organizations filmed themselves, sometimes heavily armed or waving extremist symbols, at demonstrations in at least 20 cities in recent days, from Boston to Buffalo to Richmond, Va., to Dallas to Salem, Ore.

Note that this is evidence that they were "at the protest sites" but not much else. Intentions to incite civil war are widely documented online, but I'm not seeing strong evidence that they are directly involved in anything like looting or property damage.

Comment: There are certainly many images online of (apparently) white people participating in vandalism.

Comment: @DanielRHicks, yes, but none that I've seen so far with any clear indication of their politics, which is central to the question asked here.

Comment: There are reasonably credible reports online of a loosely-knit right-wing anarchist organization which is encouraging the violence.

Comment: https://www.startribune.com/attention-turns-more-to-the-role-of-out-of-state-rioters/570897402/

Comment: "State officials also gave conflicting accounts of whether the suspected agitators came from the ranks of white supremacists exploiting the rage over Floyd’s death, or left wing anarchists bent on turning the anger toward their ends of discrediting the police." Not much there as far as concrete evidence goes. Some out of state arrests, mention of Bugaloo Bois, etc.

Comment: I've seen more specific reports, but I can't locate them right now.  And a big problem with nailing this down is that the Bugaloo Bois and their kin intentionally maintain a very loosely-connect organization, making it hard to trace connections.

Comment: @DanielRHicks It also makes direct questions like "Are you a member of the Bugaloo Bois?" easy to avoid. Without that, its kind of hard to come to hard conclusions. How much participation on far-right websites is required to infer a "yes".

Comment: From CNN:  https://www.cnn.com/2020/06/01/us/us-protests-monday-george-floyd/index.html

Comment: Isn some cases, agitators aren't even local. In Miami, Police Chief Jorge Colina said "of the 57 people that were arrested, 13 of those 57 live in the city of Miami."
Some of those who have been arrested are from Michigan, Georgia, New York and at least three are from Minnesota, he said. Others wouldn't say where they're from. ...

Comment: ... There are other signs that looters aren't really protesters, but rather outside opportunists. In Chicago, Mayor Lori Lightfoot said looters were organized and possibly came from outside of the city.
"There clearly was coordination, they were clearly listening to our radio traffic," she said.

"The number of U-Haul trucks that magically showed up in front of stores, car caravans that dropped people off and broke windows and then were hustling the goods out into the backs of the cars -- absolutely, it was organized."

Comment: I don’t think we need “signs” that looters aren’t protestors: they’re looters. That pretty much excludes them from being legitimate protestors. If they’re looting, they’re looters, not protestors (and unfairly giving a bad name to those legitimately protesting).

Comment: It is noteworthy that the NYT makes the assertion without actually naming any specific groups, and that the description of "extremist symbols" explicitly says "the names of both African-Americans and white people killed in confrontations with the police".

Comment: This seems to be indicative of extreme, racist, views, saying that white people are not legitimate protestors or white people who are killed by police are not relevant. Police violence has always been a bipartisan issue. Looting, unfortunately, is bipartisan too. I tried to find credible reports of white supremacist groups mixing with protests to agitate violence, but I couldn't find anything. There's a lot of tinfoil reports out there creating noise.

Comment: @gszavae I didn't want to say it earlier, but the NYT is increasingly "tinfoil" in its reporting, so I don't think it's trustworthy, at least on this topic.

Answer (score 8):

The [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/health/prosecutors-3-men-plotted-to-terrorize-vegas-protests/2020/06/03/98d87976-a5f8-11ea-898e-b21b9a83f792_story.html):

> LAS VEGAS — Three Nevada men with ties to a loose movement of
>   right-wing extremists advocating the overthrow of the U.S. government
>   have been arrested on terrorism-related charges in what authorities
>   say was a conspiracy to spark violence during recent protests in Las
>   Vegas.

The men were arrested while preparing Molotov cocktails and were in possession of fireworks, according to the report. It also states that they intended to join the protests and to firebomb a power station. They identified with the so-called boogaloo movement, which advocates a second Civil War.

Comment: OK.  All that proves is that three Nevada men with ties to a loose movement of right-wing extremists were arrested.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think it does more than that. They were attempting to join the protests, which applies directly to the question asked. Given the movement's focus on the Civil War, it clearly has white supremacist connections. I find it difficult to read this as anything but "white supremacists mixing in with groups protesting Goerge Floyd's death," which is the question asked.

Comment: @user34258 From what I've read, the Boogaloo fixation is on a *coming* civil war, not the previous one. They explicitly want to violently overthrow the government. Exact reasons and for what end seem vague.

Comment: The "Boogaloo" movement is definitely trying to prepare for and incite an insurgency against federal and local governments in the US. While there are very significant factions in the movement who advocate white supremacy, according to this article by investigative journalists with a lot of experience in researching and reporting on far-right groups there are some nuances in the loose coalition: https://www.bellingcat.com/news/2020/05/27/the-boogaloo-movement-is-not-what-you-think/